# Calculating the number of specific consecutive equal values in a vectorized way in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

Let's say we have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
In [1]:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], columns=['in'])
df
Out[1]: 
   in
0   0
1   1
2   0
3   0
4   1
5   1
6   0
7   1
8   1
9   1
```

How to count the number of consecutive ones **in a vectorized way** in pandas? I would like to have a result like this:

```
   in  out
0   0    0
1   1    1
2   0    0
3   0    0
4   1    1
5   1    2
6   0    0
7   1    1
8   1    2
9   1    3
```

Something like a vectorized cumsum operation that resets on a specific condition.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do something like this(credit goes to: [how to emulate itertools.groupby with a series/dataframe?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pydata/V3p37GRxgNY/Ca3mmXikYUwJ)):

```
>>> df['in'].groupby((df['in'] != df['in'].shift()).cumsum()).cumsum()
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    1
5    2
6    0
7    1
8    2
9    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary would you do a pull-request to add this to the cookbook, somewhere in this section: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#grouping