# python pandas average number of consecutive values

Tags: python, pandas

I have an pandas data frame and I want the average number of consecutive values in a row. For example, for the following data

```
   a b c d e f g h i j k l 
p1 0 0 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 4 4 1
p2 0 4 4 0 4 4 0 1 4 4 0 1
```

so the average number of consecutive 4's for p1 is (6+2)/2 = 4 and for p2 is (2+2+2)/3 = 2

Is there also a way to find the min and max number of consecutive values? i.e. max for p1 is 6.

Comment: Please understand the meaning of consecutive numbers first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transpose your dataframe and use the method suggested in below post. You will get a dataframe of count of consecutive numbers, using which you can perform Mean, Min and Max.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29643066/12452044

Answer (score 0):

This will work for p1. To get p2, just replace the 0's with 1's whenever you see an 'iloc' function being used.

```
dict = {0:[],1:[],2:[],3:[],4:[]}
counter = 1

for i in range(len(df.iloc[0])-1):

    num = df.iloc[0,i]
    num2 = df.iloc[0,i+1]

    if num == num2:
        counter += 1
    else: 
        dict[num].append(counter)
        counter = 1
```

Then to get the average number of consecutive 4's:

```
print(sum(dict[4])/len(dict[4]))
```

And to get the max number of consecutive 4's:

```
print(max(dict[4]))
```