# rank highest continuous rows where value is True

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My question is very similar to one posted here: [Determine mean value of ‘data’ where the highest number of CONTINUOUS cond=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075164/determine-mean-value-of-data-where-the-highest-number-of-continuous-cond-true)

which has been beautifully solved by @Divakar. However, i have slightly different need. Instead of the highest maximum value, how can i get -say the 2nd highest, 3rd highest, etc. ranking?

One workaround is to reduce the original array successively with values that have been ranked and run @Divakar solution iteratively, but i was wondering if anybody has a more efficient solution

Comment: If you want to use @Divakar's answer just change the `argmax` line to `(stop-start).argsort()[-3]`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
res[res['count'] == res['count'].max()]
```

You can use

```
res[res['count'] == res['count'].sort_values().unique()[-n]]
```

For whatever `n` you want.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question specifics. It is asking for only those groups of rows that have continuous straks of True values.

Comment: @TedPetrou I was being lazy and just telling him what he needs to change in the linked question

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach a group number to each continuous set of rows. Some tricky logic will show that the following is accomplished with the following statement. The logic is based on using `diff` to find each occurrence of a 1 preceded by a 0.

```
# create fake data
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2)
df = pd.DataFrame({'cond':np.random.choice([True, False], 100), 
                   'data':np.random.rand(100)})

print(df.head(15))

     cond      data
0    True  0.544208
1   False  0.082095
2   False  0.366342
3    True  0.850851
4    True  0.406275
5   False  0.027202
6    True  0.247177
7   False  0.067144
8    True  0.993852
9   False  0.970580
10   True  0.800258
11  False  0.601817
12  False  0.764960
13  False  0.169225
14  False  0.293023

# add a group column
df['group'] = ((np.where(df.cond.diff() > 0, 1, 0) * df.cond).cumsum() +
                df.cond.iloc[0]) * df.cond

print(df.head())

     cond      data  group
0    True  0.544208      1
1   False  0.082095      0
2   False  0.366342      0
3    True  0.850851      2
4    True  0.406275      2
5   False  0.027202      0
6    True  0.247177      3
7   False  0.067144      0
8    True  0.993852      4
9   False  0.970580      0
10   True  0.800258      5
11  False  0.601817      0
12  False  0.764960      0
13  False  0.169225      0
14  False  0.293023      0

# get answer with grouping and sorting
df_final = df.query('group != 0').groupby('group')['data']\
                                 .agg(['count', 'mean'])\
                                 .sort_values('count', ascending=False)

print(df_final.head())
       count      mean
group                 
18        10  0.529819
11         8  0.630232
10         4  0.301558
16         4  0.215376
6          4  0.563013

# get result with .iloc
# if you care about ties you can select those rows that all have
# the third highest count
df.iloc[[2]]
       count      mean
group                 
10         4  0.301558
```